# Cannot allocate memory on Linux Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, ubuntu-16.04, gitlab

After I installed GitLab on my Linux Ubuntu 16.04 server, the message

> -bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory

pops up very often. I researched the problem online and it should be a memory or RAM problem.

My server has 32GB of RAM, 8 Cores and 250GB drive space. The error is strange, because the server uses no more than 19GB ram and 5% of its drive space.

Please share your experiences with me.